# SQL Server big rows fetch performance consideration

Tags: sql-server, performance, select, fetch

I am in the design phase of a new DB and have few question about row size.
I would like to embed in each table record as many information as i can, but i am not sure if big rows can affect fetch performance regardless of the select statement.

To be a bit clearer i have few mandatory field in my table, say it's a table of people :

tblPerson :

| ID | Name | Surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jhon | Doe |
| 2 | Jane | Doe |

Now image i have a ton of optional info, with 1-0 relation with the tblPerson (eg: date of birth, sex and other attribute like height and weight) in a way tha a complete row will weight few KB in the DB (image that on average record_size > 2KB and record_size < 24KB).
My first thought was to create a big table, with a lot of columns that i will filter in the select statement as needed.In that way i avoid a lot of join.
But i am concerned that big row will impact each fetch regardless of the select statement.

I use SQL Server 2019 SE, can someone explain which of the two options (or a third if you know) is considered the best practice?

Comment: You are both prematurely optimizing and ignoring a basic rule-of-thumb regarding writing efficient SQL. Any query should fetch only the columns it needs. Regardless of how you structure your tables, anyone writing SQL queries should NOT be using the lazy "select * from ..." form of SELECT. Outside of that there is no "best practice" without understanding intimately what you are actually modelling and how that information is used.

Comment: _avoid a lot of join_ Joins are an inherent fact/product of properly normalized schema.

Comment: Probably worth reading this: [SQL Server Storage Engine: LOB Storage](https://aboutsqlserver.com/2013/11/05/sql-server-storage-engine-lob-storage/). In summary though, LOB Data (large object data e,g, Images) is stored on a separate page to the in row data, so if you don't select the LOB column, it won't impact performance. So a single table with many columns is likely your best bet. As ever though, there is no single rule that works for every scenario, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: If you do not yet have an actual table with actual data that you are timing actual queries against, you are optimizing prematurely. Yes, large rows can have an impact on performance. So can splitting up those rows into many tables. It's not correct to assume one or the other will be better or best without actually offsetting it against your data needs, and it's not correct to assume that, just because a design doesn't perform optimally, it's not good enough to use (the tradeoff in manageability may well be worth it). Model it sensibly first, then index it, then go further -- if you have to.

Comment: @SMor, Jeroen Mostert : seems to me that your advice is to try before worry about "fictional" problem. I agree with you, but in that case i am interested to understand if that is a known scenario where a generale rule of thumb is already established.
SMor : clearly i do not use SELECT *, what i was asking for is if there is impact even if i do a SELECT ID only, due to table layout.

Comment: @GarethD : your answer seems to me pretty interesting, and suggest to me that i have not to worry about table "optimization" engine will do it for me, that sound great, i will dig deeper in the LOB to better know that topic that i don't know at the moment